# Riddle: Which Yom Tov can come out on different Hebrew dates?

Tags: yom-tov, riddle

In the times of Kiddush HaChodesh Shavuos which is 50 days after the start of Sefiras HaOmer could come out either 5, 6, or 7 Sivan depending on how many days Nisan and Iyar had. There is still one Yom Tov that can come out on 2 different days even with the current calendar. Which Yom Tov is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many Hassidic communities, the final day of Chanukah has particular significance as "zos chanukah."  This can be the 2nd or 3rd of Tevet, as Kislev is a month of variable length.

Comment: You got it!!!!!

Comment: Also Mazal Tov on the 10K

Answer (score 5):

Shushan Purim?  15th Adar on a regular year, 16th if the 15th is Shabbos.  (Well sortof -- Purim Meshulash.)

Comment: Good answer, however not the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[Yom Ha'atzmaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Ha%27atzmaut#Timing) can be observed on the 3rd, 4th, 5th, or 6th of Iyyar.

Comment: Good answer if you celerate it. However I am looking for something else.

Comment: I'll bet more people celebrate Y"H than "Zos Chanuka" (as such). :)

Comment: That might be tha case. However Zos Chanuka is what I was looking for:)

Answer (score 1):

Any fast d'rabanan, except 10 Teves, can be moved, but those, of course, don't qualify as the sought "Yom Tov".

Comment: Yes - I am looking for a Yom Tov.

Comment: Even 10 Tevet can be moved. We don't paskin like the avudraham who says your shittah. See Beit Yosef OC 550

Comment: @DoubleAA, ask the oldest person you know whether he's ever seen 10 _Teves_ moved. (The question specifically restricts its scope to "the current calendar", without _kidush hachodesh_.)